# send multiple images in string array format in android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Hope you all doing good. i'm working on one project in that i'm using volley multipart request for sending multiple image. in back end we are using string array(String[]) for receiving multiple image. How to pass string array of images in multipart request.

if i pass data without images it will store in database. but if i select multiple images then 500 internal server error is coming. please provide any solutions. thank you

```
        VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Service_Urls.ADD_BILL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("response", String.valueOf(response));
                try {

                    if (response.getString("response").equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                        transactFragment(Timeline_post_bill_fragment.newInstance("", ""), true);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.getString("response"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("errorrrrr", error.getMessage());
                Log.d("errorrrrr", String.valueOf(error.getCause()));
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection Timeout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> sendObj = new HashMap<>();

                
                sendObj.put("uid", user_id);
                sendObj.put("bill", fragmentSettingsBinding.enterComment.toolbarTitle.getText().toString());
                sendObj.put("money", String.valueOf(amount));
                sendObj.put("network", network);

                sendObj.put("cname", fragmentSettingsBinding.namePlaceThingHeader.titleTextView.getText().toString().trim());
                Log.d("sendObj", String.valueOf(sendObj));
                return sendObj;
            }

       

            @Override
            protected Map<String, ArrayList<DataPart>> getByteData() {
                Map<String, VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                Map<String, ArrayList<DataPart>> imageList = new HashMap<>();
                ArrayList<DataPart> dataPart = new ArrayList<>();
                String[] str = new String[100];
                String imagename = "b_attachment[]";
                for (int i = 0; i < encodedImageList.size(); i++) {
                    VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart dp = new VolleyMultipartRequest.DataPart(imagename + i, Base64.decode(String.valueOf(encodedImageList.get(i)), Base64.URL_SAFE), "image/jpeg");
                    dataPart.add(dp);

                    //params.put(imagename, new DataPart(imagename+i, Base64.decode(encodedImageList.get(i), Base64.DEFAULT), "image/jpeg"));
                }
                Log.d("response", String.valueOf(dataPart));
                imageList.put("b_attachment", dataPart);
                Log.d("sendObj", String.valueOf(imageList));
                return imageList;
            }
        };
        int socketTimeout = 500000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        multipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
    }

// volley multipart request class


public class VolleyMultipartRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {
    private final String twoHyphens = "--";
    private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> mListener;
    private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
    private Map<String, String> mHeaders;


    public VolleyMultipartRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers,
                                  Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
        this.mHeaders = headers;
    }

    public VolleyMultipartRequest(int method, String url,
                                  Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        try {
            // populate text payload
            Map<String, String> params = getParams();
            if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
            }

            // populate data byte payload
            Map<String, ArrayList<DataPart>> data = getByteData();
            if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
                dataParse(dos, data);
            }

            // close multipart form data after text and file data
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    protected Map<String, ArrayList<DataPart>> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }

    private void textParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, String> params, String encoding) throws IOException {
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                buildTextPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + encoding, uee);
        }
    }

    private void dataParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, ArrayList<DataPart>> data) throws IOException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<DataPart>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            buildDataPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
    }

    private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, ArrayList<DataPart> dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
        for (int i=0; i<dataFile.size(); i++){
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            DataPart dp = dataFile.get(i);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                    inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dp.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
            if (dp.getType() != null && !dp.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dp.getType() + lineEnd);
            }
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dp.getContent());
            int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        }
    }

    public class DataPart {
        private String fileName;
        private byte[] content;
        private String type;

        public DataPart() {
        }

        public DataPart(String name, byte[] data) {
            fileName = name;
            content = data;
        }

        public DataPart(String name, byte[] data, String mimeType) {
            fileName = name;
            content = data;
            type = mimeType;
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public byte[] getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public void setContent(byte[] content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in those strings? An image does not fit in a string. Why dont you just send the image files?

Comment: in postman i'm passing images like this b_attachment[] ... so how to pass in android code

Comment: Your post is all about strings and i asked you about it. You did not answer.

Comment: i'm passing images along with uid,bill,money,network,cname.. i need to save all data and images in db